# How to generate session id using fips 140-2 compliant random number generator in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, fips

I enabled the FIPS Local/Group Security Policy Flag in  Windows operating system's  security policy setting but i have no idea that how to generate the session id using FIPS 140-2 Compliant random number generator in asp.net. Is there any coding involved or it will be generated automatically after setting FIPS Local/Group Security Policy Flag?

Answer (score 2):

> Effects of Setting FIPS Local/Group Security Policy Flag
>
> When setting the FIPS local/group security policy flag, the behavior of several Microsoft components and products are affected. The most noticeable difference will be that the components enforcing this setting will only use those algorithms approved or allowed in FIPS mode. The specific changes to the products listed above are:

...

> Any Microsoft .NET Framework applications, such as Microsoft ASP.NET or Windows Communication Foundation (WCF), only allow algorithm implementations that are validated to FIPS 140, meaning only classes that end in "CryptoServiceProvider" or "Cng" can be used. Any attempt to create an instance of other cryptographic algorithm classes or create instances that use non-allowed algorithms will cause an InvalidOperationException exception.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/cc750357.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Many .NET Web applications can be made to be FIPS compliant by doing the following:

1) Add

```
<machineKey validationKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" decryptionKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" validation="SHA1" decryption="3DES" />
```

to the system.web section of your web application's web.config file.

You can alternatively use the GUI in IIS 7 by clicking on the web site or application, clicking Machine Key (under ASP.Net section of features view).

Ensure SHA1 or TripeDES is your Encryption and Decryption method. For encryption, I believe there is a STIG out that says you should use SHA1 for encryption.

https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/iis_7.0_web_site/2014-03-25/finding/V-26026

Check "Automatically generate at runtime" and "Generate unique key for each application" for both validation and decryption keys.

2. Also, be sure to remove Debug="true" from the first line of any pages on the server.
3. If you have debug="true" in the compilation section of your web.config, change it to debug="false"

That should make your .NET app FIPs compliant, as long as you are not doing any other non-standard encryption or decryption in the app.

Sources:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9(v=vs.100).aspx

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webtopics/2009/07/20/parser-error-message-this-implementation-is-not-part-of-the-windows-platform-fips-validated-cryptographic-algorithms-when-net-page-has-debugtrue/

http://forums.asp.net/t/1778719.aspx?+FIPS+validated+cryptographic+algorithms+3DES+machinekey+solution+didnt+work